# Php Mysql select query issue and regexp

Tags: php, mysql

in fact im working on a small php script !
I'm using thi code

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM matieres WHERE Niveaux REGEXP ',?[8],?' AND Filieres REGEXP ',?[5],?'");
```

The records on rows niveaux and filiere are like this `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`
the problem is that this query give me all rows Niveaux which contain 8 But it doesnt give me rows which contain fillieres 5. How can i solve it ?

Comment: You probably want to use `OR` instead of `AND`. This query returns rows where Niveaux contains 8 AND Filieres of the same record contains 5.

Comment: I want to select row which in niveaux contain 8 and in fillieres countain 5 ! The query give me rows with niveaux which countain 8 and it doesnt care about fillieres if it countain 5 or not

Comment: Could you show some records from your matieres table which contains 
Niveaux = 8 and Filieres = 5?

Comment: What happens when you try this:
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM matieres WHERE Niveaux REGEXP ',8,' AND Filieres REGEXP ',5,'");

Comment: @Win8_learner have as an exaample 1 row for example which have as Niveaux record (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and Fillieres record(4,1,2) and and Title record (Stack) ! In fact using this query will not get this row because it doesnt have 5 in fillieres but this query show it for me what is the problem please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:
`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM matieres WHERE Niveaux REGEXP ',8,' AND Filieres REGEXP ',5,'");`

Comment: I am glad, I could help! but just to add on, You may want to also insert records in Niveaux or Filieres as <code>,1,2,3,4,5,</code><br>instead of <code>1,2,3,4,5</code> because you are also matching preceding and succeeding comma ',' after the number

Comment: Yes i made this change ! because i've already see it in your query so i can be able to select the exact record !